# How do I get Images.xcassets under source control?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode5

So I migrated my AppIcons and LaunchImages to Images.xcassets, which is working fine it seems. But I made some modifications to the launch images, and now I went to commit the changes (I'm using a local-only git repo), and it seems Images.xcassets is not allowed to be committed to source control? Right-clicking on it, all the source control options are greyed out. And it doesn't show up in Xcode 5's new "global" commit dialog.

Seems ridiculous not to allow the assets file to be committed, am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look at your .gitIgnore file & tell what is shows

Comment: Some times it may happen me too face this problem. Have you tried by quit the xcode and re-open..

Comment: Not bad ideas, but... Restarting Xcode didn't help, same behavior. And I don't seem to have any .gitignore files anywhere in the project, and as near as I can tell I don't have a global one configured either.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in Xcode. Please file a bug report with Apple: http://bugreport.apple.com

As a workaround use the "global" commit dialog and select "File View" in the top of the side bar. The relevant files should then show up.

[image]

Comment: Great! Didn't know that control was available. Of note, now that I've added the directory and subfiles, right-clicking them in the Project Navigator still doesn't let me select any source control options...but, they do show up properly now in the global commit dialog!

Comment: 2 years later this is still a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: Still works!  Why hasn't apple fixed this yet.  3 years later and they still havent bothered to fix it...

Comment: How do I display the global commit dialog?

Answer (score 5):

Almost 2 years later, the same functionality exists for Xcode 7.1. The workaround that Matthias offers still allows you to upload assets.xcassets.

Comment: Sorry, no can do. I'm not able to comment or vote yet because I'm a noob so I can only comment on my own posts (or, at least, that's how I understood the instructions).

Comment: then , just improve your answer .

Comment: I thought my response was pretty clear - it has been two years since the original post, the problem still exists, and the workaround still provides relief...    unlike your comment "please comment it" which means what? absolutely NOTHING! glass houses... stones...

Answer (score 2):

Quitting the Xcode & reopening the project again worked!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to try something along the lines of:

```
cd /to/the/folder/

git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | grep .imageset | xargs git add

git commit...
```