# Xcode, excluded files after git commit

Tags: xcode, git, git-commit

I'm new to using git.  In Xcode, I committed my project files, and have since done two more commits.  Six of the files have control status "?" (meaning, I believe, "not under source code control").  But, those files have been around all along -- I didn't do anything special with them.

File details:

1. The four source code files have always existed and I've made no changes.
2. This `Image.xcassets` file has always existed.  I've added two more (same name) in other source code groups (and git has control of those).
3. The `icon1024.png` file has always existed (might have been added after the first commit).

[image: git source code status]

Why are those six files excluded (and not any others)?  Would there be any harm in committing those files now?

Comment: What do you call "having always existed"? Were they present in *any* commit? Try `git log --oneline -- path/to/file` to see all commits for a given file. If the output is empty, the file never was *added* so committing never considered them into the tree. git doesn't know them.

Comment: Do you have file .gitignore ? -- If you have, try check in it if that file included in .gitignore .

Comment: By "always existed" I mean those files were present at the first commit, just like the others that were included -- nothing special about them, yet excluded.  No .gitignore file.  When I did the next commit, I noticed that those files were not checked, so I checked them, and got this error for Image.xcassets "error: pathspec 'Image.xcassets' did not match any file(s) known to git"  That's a folder.  So, I checked files (1) & (3) and that commit worked.  I don't know why those some existing files were excluded initially.  Still not committed is Image.xcassets.

Comment: Asset catalog exclusion is a very old issue (2013), and the workaround mentioned here is no longer available: "How do I get Images.xcassets under source control?"
https://stackoverflow.com/q/20567075/236415